# Proving that two distinct rational fractions where all integers are bounded by $N$ are at least $1/N^2$ apart

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, fractions, rational-numbers

I recently came across an interesting problem in number theory, namely,

> Given distinct integers $a, b, c, d < N$ ( with the condition that $a<b$ and $c<d$ ) , where $N$ is also an integer :
> Prove that $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are at least $\smash[t]{\frac{1}{N^2}}$ apart.

I started by considering the difference between the fractions:
$$
\frac{a}{b} - \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad-bc}{bd} 
> \frac{ad-bc}{N^2} 
$$

Now, WLOG if $b<d$, then we have 2 cases: either $a<c$ or $a>c$. Now, if $a>c$, then the numerator of the RHS becomes greater than $1$, so the theorem is proven.

However , I cannot solve the case where $a<c$ , since now I have to consider to what extent $a$ can be lesser than $c$ to make the numerator of my fraction closer to $1$ , and I got stuck there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $|ad-bc|  \geq 1  $

Comment: Is some condition missing, such as that the fractions are in lowest terms (i.e., $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=1$) and that all of the integers are positive? Otherwise, a simple counter-example would be $N = 7$, $a = 1$, $b = 2$, $c = 3$ and $d = 6$ since we then obviously get $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: I believe some condition is missing, yes, but I think we're allowed to make some assumptions.

Comment: The problem statement says the rationals are distinct, so we don't have to worry about examples of the kind @JohnOmielan suggests.

Comment: @SammyBlack The quoted question seems to say the integers are distinct rather than the rationals being distinct

Comment: @Henry: the _title_ says that the fractions are distinct, but the body of the post doesn't. The confusion is further compounded by the fact that $a<b,c<d$ can be interpreted as either $a<b$ and $c<d$, or as $a<b<d$ and $a<c<d$.

Comment: That's true, @Henry. OP can edit to make the problem statement match the title? I'm sure that's a hypothesis, otherwise the claim isn't true!

Comment: Edited it - I understand. I hope the problem is clearer now!

Answer (score 0):

Issue is Direct Consequence of [Farey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Farey_neighbours) Sequence :

"In mathematics, the Farey sequence of order n is the sequence of completely reduced fractions , ... between 0 and 1 , ... , which when in lowest terms have denominators less than or equal to n , arranged in order of increasing size."

We can move the terms around to get fractions between $0$ & $1$ , to match the Farey Sequence.

Here $n=N-1$
We want to check the gap between Farey neighbours (skipping over neighbours will increase the over-all gap) & then get the minimum gap.

It is well-known that Farey neighours $a/b$ & $c/d$ have this :
$bc-ad=1$

Hence the gap between Farey nieghbours is $a/b-c/d=-1/bd$
We know that $b$ & $d$ can be maximum $N-1$ & $N-2$

Hence minimum gap is $1/(N-1)(N-2)$
We can not get smaller gap. We can not even get $1/N^2$.